# Accessing the post content with WP_Query

Tags: posts, wp-query

I have the following code from a template to view get the post information:

```
<?php
 $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => $count,
    'paged'          => $paged,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php echo $wp_query->post_title.'<br>';
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'd like to get display the post title etc in here but when I tried to do it like above it didn't display anything. How can I access the post information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, don't use and abuse the `$wp_query` global variable. This global should be reserved to the main query only. Use any other variable that will not create conflict.

Secondly, don't use the raw [`WP_Post` properties](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post). These are raw and unfiltered. `WP_Query` does set up postdata by default which make the use of the template tags possible.

Thirdly, **always** reset all instances of `WP_Query` to avoid any conflict with other queries on the same page

Fourthly, you have a syntax error in this line `<?php echo $wp_query->post_title.'<br>';`. You are missing a closing php tag

You can rewrite your code to something like this

```
 $args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => $count,
  'paged'          => $paged,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
    $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

### EDIT

If you need to access the `WP_Post` properties directly, you can use for instance

`echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $query->post_content );`

to display the post content,

`echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $query->post_title );`

will display the post title. The post status can be accessed by

`$query->post_status`

See a list of all available properties [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)

You have to remember, there are [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags#Post_tags) that are available during the loop to display these info without using the `WP_Post` properties

Comment: I asked the same question below: What if I want to access more things than that, like the post_status and things like that? Is not using the WP_Query like that a good idea for that?

Comment: See my update. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Slight error in your code. Once you've begun your loop (which you do after setting `$wp_query->the_post();`) then you can begin to access content from your post using WordPress template tags. So if you wanted to show a title and content it would look like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => $count,
  'paged'          => $paged,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'd recommend reading up on [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags).

Comment: What if I want to access more things than that, like the post_status and things like that?

Comment: Those are all done with template tags, see the link above. `<?php the_author(); ?>` would output the author name, `<?php echo get_post_status(); ?>` will give you the post status, etc.